# How to get selected Order Ids in block from Sales Order Grid? Magento2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-grid, admin-controller, massaction

I want to generate PDF of selected orders, Rest of the functionality is complete just wanted to get selected Ids from sales order grid. For now I am getting full list of Orders on clicking my custom action. I am passing Order collection to controller action from custom block. This is what I wanted to get in block:
[image]

My Block Class is:

```
class Order extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {


public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
                          \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
                          \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
                          ..........
                          array $data = []
) {
.....

parent::__construct($context, $data);        
}
public function getOrders() {
        //$ids = '24,23,21,16';
        $orderCollection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*');
        //$orderCollection = $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $ids]);
        return $orderCollection;
}
```

And Controller is:
    use VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Order;

```
class CreatePdf extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action  {
public function __construct(Context $context,Order $order, DirectoryList $dir, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
{

    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute() {


    //Custom Logic
}
```

I followed this link but it is not working, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884544/how-can-i-get-the-selected-order-ids-in-custom-action-in-sales-order-on-click

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution by using this class:

```
\Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
```

as used here: [Magento2 Mass Action to Sales Order Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245764/magento2-mass-action-to-sales-order-grid)